# passing parameters to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

would like to create a function that generates graphs using ggplot. For the sake of simplicity, the typical graph may be

```
ggplot(car, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + geom_point()
```

The function I would like to create is of the type

```
f <- function(DS, x, y) ggplot(DS, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

This however won't work, since x and y are not strings. This problem has been noted in previous SO questions (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r)), but without providing, in my view, a satisfactory answer. How would one modify the function above to make it work with arbitrary data frames?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One solution would be to pass x and y as string names of columns in data frame DS.

```
f <- function(DS, x, y) {    
  ggplot(DS, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()  
}
```

And then call the function as:

```
f(cars, "speed", "dist")
```

However, it seems that you don't want that? Can you provide an example why you would need different functionality? Is it because you don't want to have the arguments in the same data frame?

Comment: Beautiful. I simply didn't know this option existed. Thanks.

Comment: knew it, forgot it. rediscovered it thanks to your answer. +1

Comment: Why does the DS not require "", but x and y does? Could you please explain.

Comment: Great ! I haven't known option aes_string until I see this post.

Comment: Never knew about aes_string. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's possible the following type of codes, which only build the `aes` component.

```
require(ggplot2)

DS <- data.frame(speed=rnorm(10), dist=rnorm(10))

f <- function(DS, x, y, geom, opts=NULL) {
  aes <- eval(substitute(aes(x, y),
    list(x = substitute(x), y = substitute(y))))
  p <- ggplot(DS, aes) + geom + opts
}

p <- f(DS, speed, dist, geom_point())
p
```

However, it seems to be complicated approach.

Comment: A better approach would be to skip the conversion to text, and only build the aes component: `xName  <- substitute(x); yName  <- substitute(y); eval(substitute(aes(x, y), list(x = xName, y = yName)))`

Comment: Thank you @hadley.  I think this approach is more simple than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use do.call. Here is a one line copy paste from a working code:

```
gg <- gg + geom_rect( do.call(aes, args=list(xmin=xValues-0.5, xmax=xValues+0.5, ymin=yValues, ymax=rep(Inf, length(yValues))) ), alpha=0.2, fill=colors )
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach that I can think of is using `match.call()` to reach the variable names contained by the parameters/arguments passed to the custom plotting function and then use `eval()` on them. In this way you avoid passing them as quoted to your custom function, if you do not like that.

```
library(ggplot2)

fun <- function(df, x, y) {
    arg <- match.call()
    ggplot(df, aes(x = eval(arg$x), y = eval(arg$y))) + geom_point()
} 
fun(mpg, cty, hwy) # no need to pass the variables (column names) as quoted / as strings
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot! Can you explain the match.call argument ?

Comment: Hi @Luis. Hadley Wickham wrote about some usages of `match.call()` in the section [Capturing the current call](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#capturing-call) of his [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz) book. Maybe that helps with more details.