# How to create functions for geom_?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is related to earlier question: [R: How to pass parameters to ggplot geom_ within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077889/r-how-to-pass-parameters-to-ggplot-geom-within-a-function)

I want to be able to write utility functions that use `geom_xxxxx` functions.
Here is an example
I want to have a function that overlays milestones on any time-series plot, as shown below.

```
set.seed(0);   library(data.table);  library(ggplot2)
  DT <- data.table(
    Date = as.Date(1:100, origin="2010-01-01"),
    state = LETTERS[1:3],
    sex = c("m","f"),
    value = as.integer(runif(1:100)*100) 
  )
  dtMilestones <- data.table(
    Date = paste( "2010-15-", 2:4) %>% ydm,
    Event = paste( "Phase ", 1:3)
  )
  
  g0 <- ggplot(DT, aes(Date, value)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(state ~ sex, scales = "free")
  g0
  
  g <- g0
  for (i in 1:nrow(dtMilestones)) {
    g <- g + 
      geom_label(aes(x=dtMilestones$Date[i], max(value), label=dtMilestones$Event[i]),label.size = 0.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=dtMilestones$Date[i], linetype=5)
  }
  g
```

The code above creates the plots shown below (without milestones and with milestones)
(ignore the wrong label placement - that's for another stackoverflow question)

[image]

[image]

How can I make a function out of it?
I tried this code below and it does not work

```
  g.add.milestones <- function(dtMilestones) {
    gg <- list()
    for (i in 1:nrow(dtMilestones)) {
      gg[[i]] <- 
        geom_label(aes(x=milestones[i], max(value), label=dtMilestones$Event[i]),label.size = 0.5)
      gg[[i+nrow(dtMilestones)]]  <- 
        geom_vline(xintercept=dtMilestones$Date[i], linetype=5)
    }
  } 
  g0 + g.add.milestones(dtMilestones)
```

PS. If anyone can suggest the code that prints labels where needed (besides EACH vertical line on top of the highest point in each facet - currently all of them are printed in the )

Comment: where is `milestones` defined?

Comment: in your function, where do you get `value`?

Comment: Here is a possible solution: https://debuggr.net/solution/a2881f54-dcfa-4777-9287-eb94132d8c39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
g.add.milestones <- function(dtMilestones) {
  list(
    geom_vline(xintercept = dtMilestones$Date, linetype=5),
    geom_label(aes(x=Date, y = Inf, label=Event),
               label.size = 0.5, vjust = 1,
               data = dtMilestones)
  )
}
  
g0 + g.add.milestones(dtMilestones)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution!  (and also fast! - When I was using `for` loop to plot this,  it was taking 100 longer..). I may only wonder why this such useful functionality of geom_** functions is not documented well anywhere, as it seems.

Comment: Btw, this function is extremely handy  for applications such as http://opencanada.info/ where you have multiple timeseries that you need to relate to one another (like vaccines intakes to spike in deaths)

Answer (score 2):

The final statement in your function  - i.e. the one whose value gets returned - is a `for` loop.  `for` loops always return `NULL`.  We can see this with a short dummy example

```
x = for (i in 1) 1
x
# NULL
```

you need to return `gg` from your function by ending the function with either `gg` or `return(gg)`