# How to pass / evaluate function arguments within another function for use with ggplot?

Tags: r, eval, ggplot2

Please consider the following code:

```
test <- function(x,n){

selection<-names(x)[n]
graph <- ggplot(x, aes(factor(selection)))
graph + geom_bar()
}

test(mtcars,1)
```

It throws an error cause R can't find selection. I also played around with `substitute`, `eval` and `get` without success. I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r) and thought I understood `Joris'` answer but can't use the same trick for arguments of ggplot as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `aes_string` for this purpose. So `test` should be like this:

```
test <- function(x,n){
  graph <- ggplot(x, aes_string(x = names(x)[n]))
  graph + geom_bar()
}
```

Comment: Thanks koshke, I wish I wouldn't miss so many tiny tricks all the time. Yet it helps a bit to understand how ggplot was written.