# Pass arguments to function by string replacement

Tags: string, r, function, parsing, ggplot2

How do you wade through the `eval()`, `parse()` and other-function swamp? This should be straightforward, thus I omit the data.

Original code, with attributes in the data set and a workaround for the chart title.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = qs) + geom_bar(aes(x = G74_Q0005b)) + 
      ggtitle(attr(qs, "variable.labels")[grep("G74_Q0005b", names(qs))])
```

Here is a function that simply passes the variable name:

```
plot.label <- function(var){
  ggplot(data = qs) + geom_bar(aes(x = var)) + 
    ggtitle(attr(qs, "variable.labels")[grep(var, names(qs))])
  }
```

But obviously `var` alone is not enough and I am no programmer.

Possibly related?

- [How to pass / evaluate function arguments within another function for use with ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793306/how-to-pass-evaluate-function-arguments-within-another-function-for-use-with-g)
- [passing parameters to ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488748/passing-parameters-to-ggplot?lq=1)

Comment: second questions seems a duplicate. I let others decide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `aes_string` for the aesthetics part. This takes a variable containing a string as an argument.

```
plot.label <- function(var){
  ggplot(data = qs) + geom_bar(aes_string(x = var)) + 
    ggtitle(attr(qs, "variable.labels")[grep(var, names(qs))])
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that works...is this ggplot idiosyncrasy?

Comment: @Rico Not sure I'd call it an idiosyncrasy. The "normal" way to specify variables inside of `aes()` (unquoted variable names) is arguably more unusual, as it uses non-standard evaluation. The `aes_string` function is provided specifically for this purpose.