# ggplot inside a function: when does it not recognize arguments and when does it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following two functions:

```
library(ggplot2)

testdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(rep(c(1, 4), each = 50), rbinom(100, 50, .5)))
names(testdata) <- c("group", "value")

plotfun1 <- function(color) {
  ggplot(data = testdata, aes(x = factor(group, levels = c(0: 4)), y = value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(color = color) 
}

plotfun2 <- function(number) {
  ggplot(data = testdata, aes(x = factor(group, levels = c(0: number)), y = value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(color = 'red') 
}
```

Plotfun1 works perfectly, calling

```
plotfun1('red')
```

yields two nice red boxplots. However calling

```
plotfun2(4)
```

yields the error message:

Error in factor(group, levels = c(0:number)) : object 'number' not found

apparently in some cases ggplot is not able to 'find' the arguments of the function, and in some cases it is. What is going on here?

PS I know there is an easy work around:

```
plotfun3 <- function(number) {
  plotdata <- testdata
  plotdata$group <- factor(plotdata$group, levels = c(0: number))
  ggplot(data = plotdata, aes(x = group, y = value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(color = 'red') 
}
```

I just want to understand what is going on.)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5106782/946850, but not a duplicate.

Comment: Ah yes I only found the other question when posting this. Apparently the difference between the functions is that in plotfun1 we call the argument within aes?

Comment: Yes, that's probably the reason, but the cause lies in the internals of `ggplot`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Capture the local environment and use it when plotting:

```
plotfun2 <- function(number) {
localenv <- environment()
  ggplot(data = testdata, aes(x = factor(group, levels = c(0:number)), y = value), environment = localenv ) + 
    geom_boxplot(color = 'red') 
}

plotfun2(4)
```

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to wrap this as a function, say, `ggplot.local`, where everything "just works"?

Comment: This can be very useful, thank you!