# Adding space in the variable names with aes_string

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

This is part of my df:

```
      CWRES      ID  AGE  BMI  WGT
3     0.59034000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
4     1.81300000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
5     1.42920000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
6     0.59194000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
7     0.30886000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
8    -0.14601000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
9    -0.19776000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
10    0.74208000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
11   -0.69280000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
38   -2.42900000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
39   -0.25732000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
40   -0.49689000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
41   -0.11556000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
42    0.91036000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
43   -0.24766000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
44   -0.14962000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
45   -0.45651000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
48    0.53237000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
49   -0.53284000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
50   -0.33086000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
51   -0.56355000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
52    0.00883120  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
53   -1.00650000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
80    0.85810000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
81   -0.71715000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
82    0.44346000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
83    1.09890000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
84    0.98726000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
85    0.19667000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
86   -1.32570000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
89   -4.56920000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
90    0.75174000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
...
```

I want to plot this:

```
for(i in names(tab3)[2:5]) {
  df2 <- tab3[, c(i, "CWRES")]
  p99 = ggplot(tab3) + geom_point(aes_string(x = i, y = "CWRES"))
  print(p99)
 }
```

The problem is that if I want to change the xlab it does not work because I am using `aes_string()`.

This does not work:

```
names(tab3) = c("ID","age [years]","BMI (kg/m2)","body weight ,kg")
for(i in names(tab3)[2:5]) {
    df2 <- tab3[, c(i, "CWRES")]
  p99 = ggplot(tab3) + geom_point(aes_string(x = i, y = "CWRES"))
  print(p99)
}
```

I also tried another way:

```
namecol = c("ID","age [kgg]","BMI","bodyweight")
for(i in names(tab3)[2:5]) {
    df2 <- tab3[, c(i, "CWRES")]
  p99 = ggplot(tab3) + geom_point(aes_string(x = i, y = "CWRES")) +
  ylab("CWRES") +
    for(a in namecol[1:4]) {
      xlab(namecol[a])
    }
  print(p99)
}
```

but it does not work either.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Removed AES tag, this has nothing to do with the AES cipher (what the tag is used for), it's about AESthetic formatting of data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is that you would need backticks around names that are not syntactically valid in `aes_string`.  And putting the backticks inside the quotes is a trick that I don't know.

Prior to the existence of `aes_string`, there was [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492668/2461552) to be able to use `ggplot` in functions.  This would allow you to get around (rather than solve) the problem you are having.

This will involve creating a plotting function based on your dataset `tab3` and then going through the names of your explanatory variables with `lapply`.  Here I name the plotting function `plot1`.

```
names(tab3) = c("CWRES", "ID","age [years]","BMI (kg/m2)","body weight ,kg")

plot1 = function(variable) {
    tab3$variable = tab3[,variable]
    ggplot(tab3, aes(x = variable, y = CWRES)) +
        geom_point() +
        xlab(variable)
}

# Make a single plot
plot1(names(tab3)[3])

# Make all the plots; name object if want to save list
lapply(names(tab3)[2:5], function(x) plot1(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem cause just like @aosmith said, but it actually can be solved literally by putting backticks into the string:

```
new_names <- paste0("`", names(tab3), "`")
```

And it will work with `aes_string`.

As a side note, I also tried another simple method like this:

```
ggplot(tab3) + geom_point(aes(x = tab3[[i]], y = CWRES))
```

which worked but not as ideal because the axis label will be just the expression `tab3[[i]]`.