# lazyeval in ggplot2 within other function

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation

I have a problem and I could not find the answer in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r). I mean, I want to use the `ggplot` function within a new function, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
draw_point <- function(data, x, y ){
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x, y)) +
    geom_point()
}
```

and in result I have to use quotation marks:

```
draw_point(mtcars, "wt", "qsec")
```

Instead I want to use somehow `lazyeval` package to write this function without quotation marks:

```
draw_point(mtcars, wt, qsec)
```

It is possible to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `substitute` and `aes_q`.

```
draw_point <- function(data, x, y){
  ggplot(data, aes_q(substitute(x), substitute(y))) +
    geom_point()
}
draw_point(mtcars, wt, qsec)
```

However, if you want both `draw_point(mtcars, wt, qsec)` and `draw_point(mtcars, "wt", "qsec")` to work, you have to be a bit more creative. 
The following is a first draft of what you could do with the `lazyeval` package. This cannot handle all cases, but it should get you started.

```
draw_point <- function(data, x, y, ...){
  # lazy x and y
  ld <- as.lazy_dots(list(x = lazy(x), y = lazy(y))) 
  # combine with dots
  ld <- c(ld, lazy_dots(...))
  # change to names wherever possible 
  ld <- as.lazy_dots(lapply(ld, function(x){ 
    try(x$expr <- as.name(x$expr), silent=TRUE)
    x
  }))
  # create call
  cl <- make_call(quote(aes), ld)
  # ggplot command
  ggplot(data, eval(cl$expr)) +
    geom_point()
}

# examples that work 
draw_point(mtcars, wt, qsec, col = factor(cyl))
draw_point(mtcars, "wt", "qsec")
draw_point(mtcars, wt, 'qsec', col = factor(cyl))

# examples that doesn't work
draw_point(mtcars, "wt", "qsec", col = "factor(cyl)")
```