# scale_x_discrete and positioning in x axis

Tags: r

I am trying to add significancy bar to may grouped barplot using geom_signif in R. The problem is that, since I have applied scale_x_discrete on x axis, I can't define numeric values like xmin and xmax for the begining and ending point of the significancy bar.

```
x=ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition ,x=names ,y=M$Mean, ymin=M$Mean-M$SE, ymax=M$Mean+M$SE))+ 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=2.5)+
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(2.5) , aes(ymin =Mean))+
  geom_signif(annotations = "***", xmin=1, xmax=2, y_position=7.05, tip_length=0.03)+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=names )+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("D0", "D3", "D6" , "D12"))
```

I also did not succeed plot my desired significancy bars by using comparisons instead of xmax and xmin. The reason is that it is a grouped barplot and several conditions have the same x label.

[my barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pKdn.png)

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: We need to see some data, as well as your code, and what you have tried before we can help. Otherwise, we don't know where to start.

Comment: @brittenb Thanks. I added my barplot image as well as the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `aes( y=M$Mean...etc)` is incorrect - the aes call cannot handle the reference. see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r). If you need to use these variables, add them to your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually M$Mean is name of one the columns of my dataframe (data) and that section of the code is working properly.