# Plotting data from function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, functional-programming

I want to plot data from function. For example:

Make data and load libraries:

```
# Load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# Create Data
data <- data.frame(
  group=LETTERS[1:5],
  value=c(13,7,9,21,2)
)
```

This plotting works as intended:

```
# Basic piechart
ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +

  theme_void() # remove background, grid, numeric labels
```

But if I try to plot from inside of function:

```
a <- function(data)
{
  # Basic piechart
  ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +

    theme_void() # remove background, grid, numeric labels
  return()
}


a(data)
```

it just gives me output:

```
NULL
```

without drawing any plot.

**Question:** How to make draw plot from function in my example?

*example taken from: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options to make your function work.

## Option - I

Remove the line  `return ()`, which basically returns `NULL` when the function finishes (your plot is local to the function `a`, and the plot is not accessible outside the function, and no parameter is passed to return).

```r
a <- function(data)
{
  # Basic piechart
  ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +
    theme_void() # remove background, grid, numeric labels
}
```

## Option-II

Save your plot on a local variable to the function and return it up on completion.

```r
a <- function(data)
{
  # Basic piechart
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +
   theme_void() # remove background, grid, numeric labels
  return(p)
}
```

## Option - III

Use `environment = environment()` which sets the environment variable explicitly to the current environment when calling `ggplot`. You can read more about at [Use of ggplot() within another function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r).

```r
a <- function(data)
{
  # Basic piechart
  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group), environment = environment()) 
    p + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +  
    
    theme_void() # remove background, grid, numeric labels
  
}
```

Now you can use `a(data)` to print the output.

## Output

[image: ego_function]

Comment: So, does the `environment = environment()` makes visible all global variables for `ggplot`? If no, what it does? If yes, why it is necessary and is there any other way that does not expose all global variables to `ggplot` that is called inside function?

Comment: Have a look [Use of ggplot() within another function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r) for alternatives and discussions.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that `environment = environment()` makes visible for `ggplot` all global variables?

Comment: Thank you. Updates where very useful.