# Scatterplot function that can change based on variables for axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

I am trying to write a function that seems like it should be very simple but I am having problems with it. I want to write a function that takes in three arguements: a dataframe, x-axis variable and y-axis variable. Based on these, I want it to return a scatterplot in which the x-axis variable and y-axis variable can be changed. This is the very basic function I wrote:

```
scatter_plot <- function(dataframe, x_input, y_input) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = dataframe) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x_input, y = y_input),
    )
}
```

For reproducibility, consider the dataset `midwest` that is in the `ggplot2` package. The code I wrote does not produce errors when I run it, but when I try to pass arguments into it, such as

```
scatter_plot(midwest, percollege, percpovertyknown)
```

the function returns

> "*Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'percollege' not found*"

It seems like it does not recognize the variables in the argument, but I have been playing around with the function for quite some time and I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me with how to fix this so my function works correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of ggplot() within another function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r)

Comment: I often use `aes_string`, which also should be one of the answers in the thread I posted above. I'd think that can be nicely fitted in the code that you have now.

Comment: @4rj4n apparently, `aes_string` is soft-deprecated now: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I hadn't noticed that. So `aes_` is recommended there, which also can take strings, I see.

Comment: @4rj4n no, none of the functions mentioned on this site. It is recommended to do tidy evaluation as you can see in the answers here or on https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html

Comment: Ah, I see now. I missed the life cycle header, mentioning all of it has been soft-deprecated. Well, time to change my code for newer analyses then.
I earlier flagged this question as duplicate, which in principle is true, but the original question I refer to has not been updated to include answers that use tidy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` uses non standard evaluation (NSE), which makes using its facilities in functions slightly more complicated than you expect.  Here's a version of your function that works for me.

```
scatter_plot <- function(dataframe, x_input, y_input) {
  qX <- enquo(x_input)
  qY <- enquo(y_input)
  plot <- ggplot(data = dataframe) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = !! qX, y = !! qY),
    )
  return(plot)
}
```

As you've assigned your plot to an object, I've added a `return` statement.

See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more information on NSE.

Comment: I would use `aes(x = {{ x_input }}, y = {{ y_input }})`

Answer (score 0):

Using `!!rlang::ensym()` in your function should work.

```
scatter_plot <- function(dataframe, x_input, y_input) {
  plot <- ggplot(data = dataframe) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = !!rlang::ensym(x_input), y = !!rlang::ensym(y_input)))
  plot
}
```

Example

```
scatter_plot(midwest, percollege, percpovertyknown)
```

[image]

Comment: I would use `aes(x = {{ x_input }}, y = {{ y_input }})`.

Comment: I didn't know about double curly brackets.. What is the difference between them and `ensym`? Do you have a reference link in which I can study their usage?

Comment: There is https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/programming.html

The main difference is that with curly brackets you can pass any expression, not just variable names. For instance `colour = `cut_number(x, 3)` will work properly if you tunnel the argument with `{{`.