# "Error in as.double(x)..." and other error message while creating a function to summarize and graph

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plyr

long time listener and first time caller here
For a project I am working on, I often end up graphing the same graphs with just different response variables. So I am trying to write a function based on a `ddply()` code and a `ggplot()` code I keep reusing:

(df.smpl is the dataframe I am working with, genotype is the treatment I am interested in, and var is the stand-in for a response variable I am interested in)

```
const.gra<-function(var){
  ## First, summarise the data to be used in subsequent ggplot code
  summ<-ddply(df.smpl, "genotype", summarise,
                        N = length(var),
                        mean = mean(var),
                        sd = sd(var),
                        se = sd/sqrt(N))
  # Now graph
  ggplot(data=summ, aes(genotype, mean))+
    geom_col(position = "dodge")+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se),
                  width=.2,
                  position=position_dodge(.9))+
    scale_x_discrete(name = "Genotype",
                     breaks=c("K","PW", "AW"),
                     labels=c("Plant K", "Plant PW", "Plant AW"))+
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Title")+
    theme(legend.position = "none", 
          legend.justification = c(1,1),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.text = element_text (size = 14),
          legend.title = element_text (size = 14))
}
const.gra(df.smpl$bgbm..mg.)
```

But the above codes yield the following error messages.

> ```
> Error in as.double(x) : 
> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In mean.default(var) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> ```

Tried solving it on my own but have been very unsuccessful so far. The codes run just fine if I were to run them verbatim outside of the function.

Based on some answers I have found online re: the error code, I tried subbing out some strings that sounded like they could be common base r function names or something, but no luck thus far... :(

Comment: I suspect you are a victim of tidyverse’s non-standard evaluation.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080469/scatterplot-function-that-can-change-based-on-variables-for-axes) or [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) amongst many possibles.

Comment: thank you @Limey After skimming through what you have shared, I think you are probably right. I will read up on them. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to unpack here.

First, the error messages are due to `sd(var)` and `mean(var)`. At some point in the `plyr::summarise` call, R looks for a column called `var` in your data frame, and after not finding one, it looks in the parent environment from where you're calling `const.gra`. There it finds the `var` function in the `stats` package that is loaded by default in R, and then passes it to functions that don't like other functions as their argument.

The second thing to note is that the `plyr` package is retired and the [developer's repo](https://github.com/hadley/plyr#status-) recommends `dplyr` be used instead.

Based on some quick experiments I did now, I don't think `plyr` supports the current non-standard evaluation syntax that is available in `tidyverse` packages. Luckily, there seems to be enough compatibility between both, that you can use `dplyr::summarise` inside the `plyr::ddply` call and things will work without changing too much code.

That said, I would advise you drop `plyr` completely. Below you can find both ways of doing things. Be aware that if you load `dplyr` first and then `plyr`, then the former's `summarise` will be masked by the latter.

```r
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

func_nse <- function(y, x) {
  ddply(y, "vs", summarise,
                 N = length({{x}}),
                 mean = mean({{x}}),
                 sd = sd({{x}}),
                 se = sd/sqrt(N))
}

func_dplyr <- function(y, x) {
  y %>%
  group_by(vs) %>%
  summarise(N = length({{x}}),
            mean = mean({{x}}),
            sd = sd({{x}}),
            se = sd/sqrt(N))
}

func_nse(mtcars, mpg)
func_dplyr(mtcars, mpg)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am just reading up on tidy eval. Learning a lot!