# R environments and function call stacks

Tags: r, scope, environment-variables

I am trying to use `get` in series of function calls, but the lookup of the object names seems to skip environments.  For example:

```
foo <- 1 # variable in .GlobalEnv

getter <- function(x) {get(x)}
getter("foo") # returns 1, which is expected

f1 <- function() {
  foo <- 2 # local variable in the function scope
  getter("foo")
}

f1() # still returns 1, would've expected to return 2
```

Why is it that calling `f1` returns the `foo` in the global environment and not the `foo` in the calling function's environment?

How do I have `get` look in the calling function's environment?  Setting `pos = sys.parent()` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define `getter` to look in the parent frame, it works:

```
getter <- function(x) get(x, envir=parent.frame())
```

Then:

```
getter("foo")
[1] 1

f1()
[1] 2
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Why is it that parent.frame() works but not sys.parent()?  Is there a document that discusses how all these different functions work, and the differences between referring to environments by number or by name?

Comment: @hgcrpd `sys.parent` returns an integer, not the frame/environment.  `parent.frame` uses the `sys.parent` information with `sys.frame` to get the frame (not just its integer value).

Answer (score 17):

You are being tripped up by the subtle differences between frames and environments (which is even more subtle since frames are environments, or maybe environments are frames) and the difference between [lexical and dynamic scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840769/scoping-and-functions-in-r-2-11-1-whats-going-wrong).  There are some details in the help page for [`parent.frame`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/parent.frame) and other places spread across various documentation.

To try and simplify:

Your `getter` function has its own [environment](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/environment) where variables local to that function are stored (`x` in this case).  Since R is lexically scoped that means that the functions environment has a parent environment which is defined by where the function is defined, the global environment in this case (if it were defined inside of another function then the parent environment would be the env for that function).

When you call `f1` and it calls `getter` then getter tries to find the variable `foo`, it first looks in its own environment, does not find it there, then looks in its parent environment which is the global env and finds `foo` with the value of 1.

Your thinking goes along the lines of dynamic scoping, which the frames approximate.  When `f1` is called it gets its own environment (within which `foo` will be assigned the value 2), then it calls the `getter` function.  The environment of `foo` is not the parent of `getter`'s env (lexical scoping), but the environment of `f1` is the parent frame of `getter` since `getter` was called from `f1`, so to look in the environment of `f1` you need to tell the `get` function to look in the parent frame rather than the parent environment.

The summary of this is that the parent environment is the environment where a function was defined (lexical scoping), the parent frame is the frame/environment from which the function was called (simulated dynamic scoping).

Comment: +1 Very nice explanation, thank you. This deserves to be the accepted answer, If you merge my code solution in, I shall remove my answer, so yours can get accepted.

Comment: @Andrie I think both answers are good, yours solved the immediate problem and mine gave the background.  I have no problem with both remaining and which is the accepted should be the decision of the original poster.  I do appreciate your upvote.